# CISCO EPC3008 vs CISCO EPC3208 = has either of them had security issues?

Tags: cisco

I need to choose between one of those modems.
Has either of them had known security vulnerabilities and were they patched?

Comment: Possible duplicate of? [How to find out what vulnerabilities X product has/had](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/185923/how-to-find-out-what-vulnerabilities-x-product-has-had-has)

Answer (score 2):

Freddins,

I realise this is a very late answer however to answer your question. Yes both of them have HAD vulnerabilities in the past (that's a given) [Cisco Security Advisories and Alerts](https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/publicationListing.x) this is something that we use frequently at my company (You can setup email alerts for this as well)

To answer your question in regards to what they've been affected by please use the following links. It's worth noting that every known vulnerability has already been patched and can be avoided with a simple version upgrade.

---

**EPC3008**

- [Remote Code Execution Vulnerability](https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/ciscosa-20140716-cm)
- [Cable Modem Cross-Site Scripting Vulnerability](https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/Cisco-SA-20120613-CVE-2012-3047)
- [OpenSSL Hearbeat Extension Vulnerability](https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-20140409-heartbleed)

---

**EPC3208**

- [Remote Code Execution Vulnerability](https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/ciscosa-20140716-cm)

---

From what I can tell, it looks like the EPC3208 was NEVER affected by the Cross-Site scripting vulnerability or the OpenSSL Heartbeat vulnerability. Please take this with a pinch of salt, whilst Cisco tries to catch everything they cannot report on something they don't know!

These are not popular products meaning it's fairly likely there are some unknown vulnerabilities however there is no point speculating over that, just take it as you will and perhaps keep up to date with the Cisco Security Advisories as much as possible!

Comment: Hello Josh and welcome. You just revived a Q that should have been closed down when it was asked in the first place. I just rejected your edit request (as it doesn't change anything about the content of the question itself) and voted to close the question finally.

Comment: @SmokeDispenser Hello, thank you for welcoming me. I disagree that this question should have been closed down in the first place. The first part of the question I deem to be on topic as he's not asking which device he should go with he's asking for advice on what vulnerabilities affect said device. I will agree the second part of the question is off-topic and is in-fact a product recommendation (As he's asking for a link to a page). I've further edited this question to remove the second half so that the question remains on topic as defined in the scope. Thank you.

Comment: That would fall under “clearly conflicts with the authors intend” and should be rejected as an edit as well.

Comment: @SmokeDispenser I don't believe so. Because the second part was an addition to his question. The first part has always remained the same. I would agree if the second part wasn't an addition, but it clearly was therefor I would argue that it does not fall under "clearly conflicts with the authors intent" as his original question is still valid under scope plus doesn't mention anything to do with the second half of his question